# Are there commands to install Ubuntu from USB?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, usb, chroot, debootstrap

I currently have Q4os installed.

What command can I use to install Lubuntu from files on USB? I can't boot install from USB and mini install doesn't have wireless internet installed.

Comment: Q4OS is Debian based, it might support mkusb which is a great tool for making an installer USB.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of either of the questions it's marked as duplicate of in my opinion. The question is how to install Ubuntu from within q4OS as I read it.

Comment: @vidarlo I would consider that off topic. We can't be expected to know  how Q4OS works.

Comment: @Rinzwind Off topic **would** be a valid close reason... But the dupes was not a valid close reason.

Comment: Why can't you "boot install from USB"?  Add this detail to your question, and I'm sure someone would be happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

You may, using [`debootstrap`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/apds04.html). This is not for the faint of heart, as it is mostly a manual procedure, but it's absolutely possible.

First you will have to make space. Shrink one of the existing partitions, so you have at least a gigabyte or three for Ubuntu. This can be increased later, when you have booted into Ubuntu, and are ready to remove your current OS. `gparted` is a nice GUI tool for working with partitions.

Next, mount your new partition somewhere nice. I will use `/mnt` for this in this text.

Also run the following command, and save the UUID for later! Substitute sdb1 for whatever partition you set up.

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ubuntu" UUID="a15e52e5-a5e3-4643-a657-43ce87f9aa00" TYPE="ext4"
```

### Getting debootstrap

At this stage I assumed `/mnt/` is mounted.

First step is to download [debootstrap](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/debootstrap/). At the time of writing, [debootstrap_1.0.95.tar.gz](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.95.tar.gz) is the latest version:

```
[/tmp]$ wget "http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.95.tar.gz"
[/tmp]$ tar zxf debootstrap_1.0.95.tar.gz 
[/tmp]$ cd debootstrap-1.0.95/
[/tmp/debootstrap-1.0.95]$ export DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=`pwd`
[/tmp/debootstrap-1.0.95]$ sudo DEBOOTSTRAP_DIR=`pwd` ./debootstrap --arch=amd64 xenial /mnt http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
[removed lots of output of debootstrap fetching packages]
```

This step takes some time, as the base system is downloaded and unpacked into `/mnt`. It should end with `I: Base system installed successfully.`

Then we need to bind mount some system directories, so information about the machine is available inside the chroot:

```
# sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
# sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
# sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/sys
# sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
```

### chroot into the new system

```
[/tmp/debootstrap-1.0.95]$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@hannah:/#
```

This is a functioning Ubuntu system, albeit a minimal one.
First step is probably to install a few packages, such as nano.
You will get error messages complaining that devices are unavailable and so forth. This is normal. Ignore them.

All commands from now on is run inside the chroot environment.

Mount the virtual /proc and /sys fs:
    # mount -t proc proc /proc
    # mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys

### Configure fstab

The `fstab` is blank. Edit it with nano:

```
# nano /etc/fstab
```

Add a line like

```
UUID=a15e52e5-a5e3-4643-a657-43ce87f9aa00  /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

where the UUID is the one you saved above.

### Update your system

```
# echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
# echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Time to install a kernel!

```
# apt-cache search linux-image
```

will list available kernels. Pick a suitable one. For me this was `linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic`, which was installed with

```
# apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic
```

This should ask you where you want to install the bootloader. This is typically the main drive, `/dev/sda` or similar. **This will overwrite your current bootloader and make your current system unbootable!**

### Adding a user

```
# adduser foo
 ##Answer adduser with password, name and so on
# usermod -aG sudo username
```

The last command will add sudo permissions for the user.

### Misc things to configure

You probably want to configure those items.

Timezone:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Locales:

# dpkg-reconfigure locales

### Install lubuntu-desktop

```
# apt-get lubuntu-desktop
```

This will install the meta-package lubuntu-desktop which depends on all you need for a standard lubuntu desktop. This takes a little while, as it is many packages. This will probably fail, as blueman will refuse to work without a running, proper system. Ignore it, and remove it with `apt-get remove blueman`.

This should be more or less it. Reboot into your new system, and log in.